# Upgrading bootstrap_package fails

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm upgrading bootstrap_package from 7.0.5 to 8.06.
First I got the error

> Given select field item list was not found

Event the install tool could not be used.

So I commented out the lines 49-71 in typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content_general_columns.php which leading to the problem.  I assumed the coming upgrading wizard in install tool will fix that.

Now in upgrade wizard in install tool I get the fatal error:

> Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Install\Updates\SectionFrameToFrameClassUpdate' not found in xxx/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Classes/Updates/SectionFrameToFrameClassUpdate.php on line 16

I think that's the needed update wizard which would solve the first error

TYPO3 Core Version is 7.6.23

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `bootstrap_package` version `8.0.6` Not supported for TYPO3 7.6.23.

So, You need to install `bootstrap_package version 7.1.0` for TYPO3 7.6.x

You can see here list of boostrap_package with TYPO3 version support.
[Click Here](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package/)

Comment: Oh, it was shown in Extension Manager so I assumed its ok. Thanks